# rSync only X file between Dev directory and Live site

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to sync web files from a Dev system to our live system, but I've tried two ways and it's just not doing what I want. Files that I don't want are being sent, etc.

I've tried these two ways:

```
rsync -av --progress --include="*.php" --include="*.js" --include="*.css" --include="*/" --exclude="*" --exclude=config.php /home/1/www/* /home/2/www/

rsync -av --progress --exclude="*" --include="*.php" --include="*.js" --include="*.css" --exclude=config.php /home/1/www/* /home/2/www/
```

Neither way is working good. In both ways other files besides PHP, JS and CSS files are synced (like images) and both config files are synced and according to both ways the config.php files are not supposed to be synced.

Comment: Remove the * so `/home/1/www/ /home/2/www/`.

Comment: Still brings over the config.php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out moving things around a bit. The trick is to `exclude` the config.php file before `including` all php files.

So the final line would be:

```
rsync -av --progress --include="*/" --exclude=config.php --include="*.php" --include="*.js" --include="*.css" --include="*.tpl" --exclude="*" /home/1/www/ /home/2/www/
```